# LeetCode 641: Design Circular Deque

Tags: c++, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge, c++17

I'm posting a solution for LeetCode's "Design Circular Deque". If you'd like to review, please do so. Thank you!

#### [Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/design-circular-deque/)

Design your implementation of the circular double-ended queue (deque).

Your implementation should support following operations:

- `MyCircularDeque(k)`: Constructor, set the size of the deque to be k.
- `insertFront()`: Adds an item at the front of Deque. Return true if the operation is successful.
- `insertLast()`: Adds an item at the rear of Deque. Return true if the operation is successful.
- `deleteFront()`: Deletes an item from the front of Deque. Return true if the operation is successful.
- `deleteLast()`: Deletes an item from the rear of Deque. Return true if the operation is successful.
- `getFront()`: Gets the front item from the Deque. If the deque is empty, return -1.
- `getRear()`: Gets the last item from Deque. If the deque is empty, return -1.
- `isEmpty()`: Checks whether Deque is empty or not.
- `isFull()`: Checks whether Deque is full or not.

#### Example:

```
MyCircularDeque circularDeque = new MycircularDeque(3); // set the size to be 3
circularDeque.insertLast(1);            // return true
circularDeque.insertLast(2);            // return true
circularDeque.insertFront(3);           // return true
circularDeque.insertFront(4);           // return false, the queue is full
circularDeque.getRear();            // return 2
circularDeque.isFull();             // return true
circularDeque.deleteLast();         // return true
circularDeque.insertFront(4);           // return true
circularDeque.getFront();           // return 4
```

#### Note:

- All values will be in the range of [0, 1000].
- The number of operations will be in the range of [1, 1000].
- Please do not use the built-in Deque library.

#### Code:

```
// The following block might slightly improve the execution time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);
    return 0;
}();

// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

struct MyCircularDeque {
        MyCircularDeque(int k): stream(k, 0), counts(0), k(k), head(k - 1), tail(0) {}

        const bool insertFront(
            const int value
        ) {
            if (isFull()) {
                return false;
            }

            stream[head] = value;
            --head;
            head += k;
            head %= k;
            ++counts;

            return true;
        }

        const bool insertLast(const int value) {
            if (isFull()) {
                return false;
            }

            stream[tail] = value;
            ++tail;
            tail %= k;
            ++counts;

            return true;
        }

        const bool deleteFront() {
            if (isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }

            ++head;
            head %= k;
            --counts;

            return true;
        }

        const bool deleteLast() {
            if (isEmpty()) {
                return false;
            }

            --tail;
            tail += k;
            tail %= k;
            --counts;

            return true;
        }

        const int getFront() {
            return isEmpty() ? -1 : stream[(head + 1) % k];
        }

        const int getRear() {
            return isEmpty() ? -1 : stream[(tail - 1 + k) % k];
        }

        const bool isEmpty() {
            return !counts;
        }

        const bool isFull() {
            return counts == k;
        }

    private:
        using ValueType = std::uint_fast16_t;
        std::vector<ValueType> stream;
        ValueType counts;
        ValueType k;
        ValueType head;
        ValueType tail;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Using the same type for the deque contents *and* the sizes/indices (`k, count, head, tail`) feels wrong. At least, `k` and `count` should be `std::vector::size_type`.
- Since you are backing up the deque with `std::vector`, making `head` and `tail` the `std::vector::iterator` looks more idiomatic.
- `k` is not the most descriptive name. Consider `capacity`.
- I am not sure that `std::vector` is the best container to back up the fixed size deque. After all, the point of `std::vector` is to have a dynamic size. `std::array`, or even a plain old C-style array, looks more natural.

Comment: @Emma I wish there was one.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is a theme for your code: `const`, where you've put it, has no benefit; and it's missing from other places that it should be there. Every single function in `MyCircularDeque` should drop the `const` out front, because those return values are scalar so marking them `const` has literally no effect. `insertLast(const int value)` has slightly more effect but is really not important.

The most important place to put `const` is to modify the const-ness of `this` for your `get` and `is` methods. They need to have `const` added *after* the parentheses. This registers a promise that the methods do not modify any members.

Comment: declaring a parameter const *does* have an effect. It makes sure that you will never modify the value. All in all, it is a good practice to declare variables that you will not modify `const` or `constexpr` if the value can be calculated at compile-time. [Use of const in function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/117293/use-of-const-for-function-parameters#:~:text=Up%20vote%205-,const%20is%20pointless%20when%20the%20argument%20is%20passed%20by%20value,to%20modify%20the%20passed%20value.&text=If%20the%20function%20was%20not,result%20in%20a%20compiler%20warning.)

Answer (score 3):

You can call `stream.reserve(k)` in the constructor to improve the efficiency of the vector because you know that you will only have `k` elements, so `.reserve()` will pre-allocate the memory.

[Prefer using `std::size_t` over `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/994288/size-t-vs-int-in-c-and-or-c)
`int k` would be `std::size_t k`

You haven't declared a [copy constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) nor a [copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment). This can cause issues if you wanted to assign one `Deque` to another.

[Inlining](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline)  some member functions of your `struct` like `isEmpty()`, `getRear()`, `getFront()` **can** improve the performance of your container, but it will be a trade for space.

**If you are doing this for the sole purpose of completing the challenge, you can ignore the next part**

### Templates

Right now, your `deque` is bound to use `std::uint_fast16_t`. But what if I wanted to make a `deque` of names? Or a `deque` of different decimal values? I can't just create 15 classes for each of the data types.

Hence, I will use [templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/templates) in C++ so I can create a [generic](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/generic) `deque`.

The syntax is simple

```cpp
template < typename T >
struct deque
{
    public:
        // public member functions
    private:
        std::vector< T > stream;
};
```

Now when you want to create a new deque, you can do `deque<any_data_type> my_deque`.

Wherever you would use `ValueType`, you replace it with `T`.

What C++ does is that it takes `any_data_type` and replaces `T` with that data type during **compile-time**. Implementing this in your program will teach you a lot about how templates work in C++ which will be helpful in your future projects.

[Templates in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template)

Comment: @Emma not really, I haven't been into competitive programming a lot, although i do like to solve some problems from time to time. Thanks for the feedback :)